# jQuery validation not working 100% correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple contact form, email, first & last name, subject and message. I have the standard MVC 5 validation set up, and it kind of works (I'm submitting the form using jQuery ajax if that makes a difference). If I leave the form empty and click **Send** then I ge all the right validation messages, but then if I fill in 1 02 2 items in the list and click **Send** it actually sends the mail, missing 1/2 the information.

I can show whatever code you would like to see but for now I will start with the view, the jQuery and the email view model.

**ContactEmail.cs**

```
using AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels;
using Postal;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AccessorizeForLess.Models
{
    public class ContactEmail : Email
    {
        public string To { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address!")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide your email address")]
        public string From { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide your first name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide your last name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Subject")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a subject")]
        public string SelectedSubject { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Message")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a message for the email")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public List<EmailSubjectViewModel> Subjects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
@model AccessorizeForLess.Models.ContactEmail
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Contact</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendAJAX", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "sendContactForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>
            AccessorizeForLess.net&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/accessorize5orless" target="_blank" title="Accessorize For Less On Facebook"><img src="~/Content/icon-facebook.png" /></a>
        </h4>
        <div id="sending" style="display:none;"><img src="~/Content/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
        <div style="color:red" id="MessageSent"></div>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.From, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.From, new { @id = "from" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.From)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedSubject, "Category", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSubject, new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Id", "Subject"), "- Please Select -")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedSubject)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message, new { @cols = "25", @rows = "55" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" id="SendMessage" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**My jQuery:**

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#sendContactForm").submit(function (e) {
                //alert("Clicked!");
                //prevent Default functionality
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#SendMessage").attr("disbled", true);
                $("#SendMessage").prop("value", "Sending...");
                $("#sending").css("display", "block");
                $("#MessagdSent").html("&nbsp;");

                //get the action-url of the form
                var $form = $(e.target),
                    formData = new FormData(),
                    params = $form.serializeArray()

                $.each(params, function (i, val) {
                    formData.append(val.name, val.value);
                });

                //do your own request an handle the results
                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (result) {
                        successfulSend(result);
                        resetForm($form)
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        failedSend(result);
                    }
                });

                function resetForm(form) {
                    form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
                }

                //function that is called when the message is successfully sent
                function successfulSend(result) {
                    //enable the send button
                    $("#SendMessage").attr("disbled", false);

                    //hide the sending gif
                    $("#sending").css("display", "none");

                    //change the text on the button back to Send
                    $("#SendMessage").prop("value", "Send");

                    //set focus to the from email address textbox
                    $("#From").focus();

                    $("#MessageSent").html(result.Message);
                }

                //call this function if for some reason the send fails
                function failedSend(result) {
                    $("#SendMessage").attr("disbled", false);
                    $("#sending").css("display", "none");
                    $("#SendMessage").prop("value", "Send");
                    $("#MessageSent").text(result.ErrorMessage);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why it doesn't keep validating until all required information is provided?

Comment: jquery unobtrusive validation works when you submit the form, but your not submitting it (your posting it via ajax and actually cancel the `.submit()` event) so the validators `.validate()` function is not being called (which in turn would cancel the submit event if the form was invalid)

Comment: But it is validating, it validates an empty form, but as soon as I enter data in just a single entry it lets it go by

Comment: Because you posting the form using ajax (you cancel the normal submit action). You can always test if the form is valid, and if not, just cancel the ajax call.

Comment: Side note: You can just use `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` and delete the `$.each(params, ...` bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .valid() on the form to check for validity and it seems to have resolved the issue. thanks @StephenMuecke for your advice. My new jQuery looks like so

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
        $("#sendContactForm").submit(function (e) {
            //get the action-url of the form
            var $form = $(e.target),
               formData = new FormData($('form').get(0));

            //prevent Default functionality
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($form.valid()) {
                $("#SendMessage").attr("disbled", true);
                $("#SendMessage").prop("value", "Sending...");
                $("#sending").css("display", "block");
                $("#MessagdSent").html("&nbsp;");

                //do your own request an handle the results
                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (result) {
                        successfulSend(result);
                        resetForm($form)
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        failedSend(result);
                    }
                });
            }               

            function resetForm(form) {
                form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
            }

            //function that is called when the message is successfully sent
            function successfulSend(result) {
                //enable the send button
                $("#SendMessage").attr("disbled", false);

                //hide the sending gif
                $("#sending").css("display", "none");

                //change the text on the button back to Send
                $("#SendMessage").prop("value", "Send");

                //set focus to the from email address textbox
                $("#From").focus();

                $("#MessageSent").html(result.Message);
            }

            //call this function if for some reason the send fails
            function failedSend(result) {
                $("#SendMessage").attr("disbled", false);
                $("#sending").css("display", "none");
                $("#SendMessage").prop("value", "Send");
                $("#MessageSent").text(result.ErrorMessage);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```